# Remove @"" from NSString or typecast NSString into variable name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I read a NSString from file and then I want to #define this as a UIColor so I can quickly change color's.

I want something to work like so:

```
#define GRAY [UIColor darkGrayColor]
```

Then read from file the string : @"GRAY" and put it in a NSString variable called kColor

And then paste this onto a backgroundcolor property like so:

```
myController.view.backgroundColor = kColor;
```

now this means I get :

```
myController.view.backgroundColor = @"GRAY";
```

I need:

```
myController.view.backgroundColor = GRAY;
```

for the #define to work. So how do i remove @"" from the string or typecast the string into a variable name? I'm not stuck on #define so if there is another way to get this to work, I'm open to that.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: where is your `define` located?

Comment: What's wrong with `myController.view.backgroundColor = GRAY;`?

Comment: What's wrong with an if-statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load the colors into a `NSDictionary`.

```
// Put this in some global scope
NSDictionary *colors = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
    [UIColor darkGrayColor], @"GRAY", nil];

// using the dictionary
myController.view.backgroundColor = [colors objectForKey:kColor];
```

Comment: That works! And is so beautiful in it's simplicity that I don't know why I haven't thought of it myself ;) Thanks for helping me get unstuck.

Answer (score 2):

When you say 'read from file the string : @"GRAY"' do you mean at application run time? if so, then you cannot use #define(s), which are happening at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Objective-C is a compiled language, so you can't use a `NSString` as if it were a piece of code. You will need a way to return a proper color from a string/NSString read from a file.

Comment: Include LLVM libraries, compile yit and dynamically link :)

Comment: You can actually.  You can turn strings into selectors or classes with `NSSelectorFromString()` and `NSClassFromString()`.

Comment: @JeremyP he's not asking about selector, but about a string that resolves to a define.

Comment: @NWCoder: I was referring to using an `NSString` as a piece of code in general.

Comment: @JeremyP: true. you can use a string as a selector of to instantiate a new class. But you can't use it as a generic piece of code that you would run with something like Javascript's `eval`. (which is apparently what OP wants to accomplish. although his/her question is not **that** clear)

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's answer is probably the best.  Since he hasn't provided any code, this is one implementation:

```
-(UIColor*) colorFromString: (NSString*) colorName
{
    static NSDictionary colors = nil;
    if (colors == nil)
    {
        colors = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                                   [UIColor darkGreyColor], @"GRAY",
                                   [UIColor blueColor], @"BLUE",
                                   // etc
                                   nil];
        [colors retain];
    }
    return [colors objectForKey: colorName];
}
```